# Using combobox to change which element selector to use Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here. Is it possible to pass a string like this? I am trying to make a generic web scraper that a user can choose which element to find by. Of course I'm getting  the error "'By' does not contain a definition for 'elementFind'"

I remember reading about creating custom classes, but I'm not sure if that would get me to where I want to go here, as I feel like you would have to modify the Selenium namespace.

```
namespace WebScraper
{
    public partial class WebScraper : Form
{
    public string url;
    public string elementFind;
    public string elementString;
    public WebScraper()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void urlBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        url = urlBox.Text;
    }

    public void elementPicker()
    {
        switch (comboBox.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                elementFind = "ID";
                break;
            case 1:
                elementFind = "Name";
                break;
            case 2:
                elementFind = "Class";
                break;
            case 3:
                elementFind = "XPath";
                break;
            case 4:
                elementFind = "CSS Selector";
                break;
            case 5:
                elementFind = "LinkText";
                break;
            case 6:
                elementFind = "Text";
                break; 
        }
    }

    private void chromeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        driver.FindElement(By.elementFind(elementString));
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a global variable as:

```
By findBy;
```

Modify your `elementPicker()` something like this:

```
public void elementPicker(string value)
{
    switch(comboBox.SelectedIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        findBy = By.Id(value);
        break;
    //Same for all case
    }
}
```

Then your code in `chromeBtn_Click` looks something like this:

```
.......
elementPicker();
driver.FindElement(findBy);
```

This is with reference to the code you posted; I am not aware about other workflow of your application.

Even better solution is to write a new function something like follows:

```
public By GetFindByType(string value)
{
    By findBy;
    //Similar switch-case as above
    return findBy;
}
```

This way, you avoid declaring global variables.